# Typescript generic object in array only match the specified Records

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/Nnavaw

So I have an array with the following definition:

```
Array<{
      id?: string;
      text?: string;
      date?: Date;
    }>
```

That interfers with the following implementation:

```
data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number | null>>>
```

How can I tell Typescript that the Array can also include other properties other than `Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number | null>>`?

Because if I'll pass an array with the following defintion it gives me this error:

```
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | null | undefined'.
```

Complete function:

```
ifAlreadyExistsString<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey>(
    data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number | null>>>,
    key: K,
    value: string,
    idKey?: H,
    idValue?: string | number | null
  ): boolean {
    return (
      data.filter((item) => {
        // If the value is found in the data array
        if (item[key] && item[key]?.trim().toLowerCase() === value.trim().toLowerCase()) {
          // Then check if the id of the value matches the found entry
          // If the ids are matching, then you are currently editing this exact entry
          // If the ids are NOT matching, then you have found a duplicate.
          if (idKey && item[idKey] && idValue) {
            return !(item[idKey] === idValue);
          } else {
            // If no idKey is provided, then we have found a duplicate.
            return true;
          }
        }

        return false;
      }).length !== 0
    );
  }
```

Comment: `data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number | Date | null>>>` fixes the error. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: No, because you modify the data type of `idKey`/`H`. The sturcture of the object could be anything but should include the Record definitions

Comment: Inference is failing to do what you want when `idKey` is not passed. Two options I see; use overloads like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w654rW), or use a `NoInfer` trick to try to prevent `data` from being used to infer `H`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPZkeN).  Let me know which, if any, of those meets your needs and I will write up an answer explaining.  If neither meets your needs, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz using the `NoInfer` trick works fine, thank you!

Comment: @jcalz Is there also a way to make the autocompletion work for `key` and `idKey`? So that you can only input required or optional properties from the model in the array? Currently I could pass `erkusdsdsd` as a key, even if that doesn't exists on the model

Comment: Autocompletion seems to be out of scope of the question as asked.  Is that needed for my answer?  If so, please [edit] the question to clarify your requirements, preferably by showing use cases.  If not, then I'm happy to advise in a different post, asssuming that you can't find the answer to your question by searching SO.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I'll do more research and open up another question if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass in an `idKey` parameter, then the compiler can't use it to infer `H`.  What you'd like to happen here is that `H` should fall back to `never`, because  `Record<never, string | number | null>` is just `{}`, and you don't want to constrain the element type of `data`.  Unfortunately what *actually* happens is that the compiler uses the `data` array type to infer `H`.  It guesses that `H` should be  `keyof (typeof data)[number]`, and then complains about it.  Oh well.

You need to step in and prevent `H` from being inferred as anything but possibly `never` when `idKey` is not passed.

---

One way to do this to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) the method so that there is one call signature for `idKey` being present and another for it being absent.  That looks like:

```
// call signature without idKey
ifAlreadyExistsString<K extends PropertyKey>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>>>,
  key: K,
  value: string,
): boolean;

// call signature with idKey
ifAlreadyExistsString<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number | null>>>,
  key: K,
  value: string,
  idKey?: H,
  idValue?: string | number | null
): boolean;

// implementation
ifAlreadyExistsString<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<H, string | number | null>>>,
  key: K,
  value: string,
  idKey?: H,
  idValue?: string | number | null
): boolean { /* snip impl */ }
```

You'll find that this now works:

```
console.log(this.ifAlreadyExistsString(data, 'text', 'no text')); // okay
/* AppComponent.ifAlreadyExistsString<"text">(
    data: Partial<Record<"text", string>>[], key: "text", value: string
  ): boolean (+1 overload) */
```

---

Another thing you could do is try to tell the compiler not to infer `H` from `data`, and to [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `never`.  You want to say that the `H` in the type of `data` is a *non-inferential type parameter usage*.  There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for a syntax to do this.  The idea is that `NoInfer<H>` would evaluate to exactly `H`, but would not be usable for inference.

The feature request is still open.  However, there are some ways to emulate `NoInfer<T>` with current TypeScript features, which work in at least some circumstances.  [One way](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) is:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

You can see that no matter what `T` is, `NoInfer<T>` will eventually evaluate to `T`.  But the compiler *defers* evaluation of `T extends any ? 0 : never` for generic `T`, and this will block inference:

```
ifAlreadyExistsString<K extends PropertyKey, H extends PropertyKey = never>(
  data: Array<Partial<Record<K, string>> & Partial<Record<NoInfer<H>, string | number | null>>>,
  key: K,
  value: string,
  idKey?: H,
  idValue?: string | number | null
): boolean { /* snip impl */ }
```

And now this works again:

```
console.log(this.ifAlreadyExistsString(data, 'text', 'no text'));
/* AppComponent.ifAlreadyExistsString<"text", never>(
     data: (Partial<Record<"text", string>> & Partial<Record<never, string | number | null>>)[], 
     key: "text", value: string, idKey?: undefined, 
     idValue?: string | number | null | undefined): boolean */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAeQG5QE4BsD2YAJjCgN7AoqK5gykCCccAwvhHPiFCAC7mUq1LjF7YArol75sACgCUAoUMQj+RMLzAAuFA2zYwATwA8FZcoCWRAPy7R2SyADmAbkEWUvKAA9edlAcnNw8LDW8AgBFNKHdPAF8APhQAXhQAbTIUa10AcgBGACYAZlyAGi9fXjyQfEq-XJR4gF13UKpVEBh8XCgAOgJnWV4AC0sYPssAMwZcbChiIwBRH3HeGABlMWDZcLAK3O8Gg9r63lz5eVcUAHoblHwAa2N224AqPWY2Di4eXkmZnMFkRlqtRJtti4TAAiI68aGJWSvZR7XQABTA2F4ljAuBMACUoKpsEQYXDoRUgi5Eol0s0Ko8oEZdLCqhSUBhceIoPZIc5kSh5LoAEb4HoLEAoWQAanyDyweEIREUbxuoXiwFC01m80WKzWEMcUIA0igqjwSCg0dh8HAcLwjMamYjXqi9AZjCYMVicXjCcTScbKXyaYkyq9GcyUEHXpzcNzeUbnOHlEKUKLxWAQG0rIDdSD9eCtkmTKbzSBLdbbfbHUyKgAJM1+C2kKt2rG1owuzxu-SGUze7G4glEmSB4NJmkoABkVsxQ79o5JJnrE+CKAAPigQOIIMKcJvt+JcLhQymLJHdDHPHGE4E+eerEQnUYAqvXtYAGpcqABKnOQ8dz3A8tx3E9QjTDNeizHMhG1IE9TBdZi2CUsm28CtWxtdsHRfBt0JbK1sJrF9uzCTQdHdfsvXnX0RwDUs12pZJZ0HOj-THFcmIA0Dd33bBAOPU8aUfIRL2jUSqFvHl7yTSTsmfJk33kr8fz-PlBOAgTePA1MRTFaDJXMCx5l4cRsElJFPCoPY+imSxcG8ORZEsbwIEUFJkmM6zbnuABJKYvBGVBpOyUgpnwcQK2ySVRlQPYUExfsBSoaYpVcqAIHSSNmhnWcMqynKbD6bYIAUEr8AAGXwAB3HAWDoKAFFSFI0mkkrHDK+QKuqursAamAmsuJQfKEO4UAAFWCyVEGCxBHmyQK4oUh4luCjkfxQCBNFm2AgtQCKoqIM0+GwIwUrG-y1tQaxSExVBtt4WbggqOLJSMSLEvmahzPmPhcCMM0iFc9dRnGJskH4P4zouqhxoC-aFLu76ADk0AmradrGFxXumlAPvEFARjALAUEO6KwBQIhxDgXBLEQGI+lhxb0sUwHp3ytz0msF9co5hTv3jKBFG80aqFM8zJQAQhcrmeaZXLWrSVShauZn4jNXBBpGsW4au7c6nlwHwbgG0MGsKAiFxngUDqomSYOyKKapmm6YZ7wmd1oQJYsrwJFidWLo1C6fclKZcUGuJrPibrehcUYUCl1qUAABleNXlA1Khg6obgas+Vh2E4bg+AUdwNXAaB4CQVAUfwPyQCmA8KEEB07RQOuG6b7ATAm5I0nSCbmkHgjMMSkBAZsVOUF0bgFVaQQaDoRgviL34+B14QujESRpDkEXXk6UQqYo3Q+09UWn3UpMo88OFr+CW-yIiXRom8J-s-7jIshyFAChKcoZwah1DhI0FosFlBH3FAMfAQwwYTHgvmUEBoUIuF2BRA4oCTggKqBcDOFgbgfCYIXH4Jd-iIOBMgosfIyRsgqHPHAZFRpulkGxYcHFlysj8Oyf8U5WK0XYUuUkDDsDcU0vxQSJ4aTyDpBUWG4kuHwgqNJRML0FIvgCEdKA9luBWxQLDFW3IH4uHESBI8J5DxaJ0ZbSCBkJQoFVOqTUuYdSUMLMhGhZZmxjzbCROsKBGzlkrMRDsL5UjbigAqJhQhewegHAIxcDEgyyWCHwucPpBEMU7o3HAK4wwpJMbxLSkjhJhgjEyK88kVEFOTB+Nmyk6mCyMaowpR5ik6VwBBfSmYjKvFDlKAUtl7KORwLIWWmUPJeQuvDa6G0hZhTJk7Y6ThEYJSSi8MWaVxmFQVnlbIXMiodUsF1HqtV6qNWakrOZ3IjknOkL1c5g0FAHy9uNKaNtdrzRZstawq1EahUertUgy1ybHWhudV5+sfmWnupjJ62Nkz7Xep9WFiBfp-ABkDEGJj4EQykCdMQELdYzMRrdL6td0ZwuejjJF+NPrE1JqCxKLtab00ZszLZRs9kFW5mzPm+UiBNOFpvMW-SZY8qNorZOhjhYf2jprbWl9RoktOFyk2ZsLZ6LerbVADLHZHWZdTVl7t+jM3FlAMyvsd4By9lnUaOdRr9PDlrG10dY48GcAnJOaQ06eHwdnQQDq84F2+MXP4ZdNQaiAA)